# Custom fonts not displayed in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, fonts

My website uses custom fonts. They work on all browsers, except Internet Explorer (version 11.0.9600).

The CSS code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'almoni-dl';
font-weight: 700; /*(bold)*/
font-style: normal;
src: url('https://assets.mywebsite.com/fonts/almoni-dl-aaa-700.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
    url('https://assets.mywebsite.com/fonts/almoni-dl-aaa-700.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('https://assets.mywebsite.com/fonts/almoni-dl-aaa-700.ttf') format('truetype');
}

html {
    font-family: 'almoni-dl','Trebuchet MS',Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
```

What I've tried so far:

1. The fonts use an absolute path to a sub-domain. The response for these fonts includes the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`. I also tried using a relative path, no luck.
2. The fonts themselves are downloaded correctly, returning code 200.
3. Cache was cleared several times.
4. The fonts' Content-Types are: woff = application/font-woff; ttf = application/octet-stream; eot = application/vnd.ms-fontobject.
5. Other websites (such as www.newyorker.com) display custom fonts correctly on the same browser.
6. I also tried the following syntax:

   ```
   @font-face {
   font-family: 'almoni-dl';
   font-weight: 700; /*(bold)*/
   font-style: normal;
   src: url('https://assets.kalir.co.il/fonts/almoni-dl-aaa-700.eot');
   src: url('https://assets.kalir.co.il/fonts/almoni-dl-aaa-700.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
       url('https://assets.kalir.co.il/fonts/almoni-dl-aaa-700.woff') format('woff'), 
       url('https://assets.kalir.co.il/fonts/almoni-dl-aaa-700.ttf') format('truetype');
   }
   ```

What else could be wrong?

Comment: and what version of IE?

Comment: version 11.0.9600

Comment: What happens if you move `font-weight` and `font-style` after `src`? It may be that IE expects the source first, and trips up on this.

Comment: `font-family` and `src` are the only required bits, and according to the spec the font-face rule is ignored if either is missing. By inserting others between, you may inadvertently be causing IE to ignore the rule.

Comment: That was a good idea, but I just tried it... it didn't work.

Comment: @user884248 Did you find any solution on this?  i am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the font-family property in css, try typing the actual full name of the font, if that doesn't work, try using the full filename (minus the extension) as the font-family. 
IE has known issues finding the font if the font-family name is different than what it expects!